# How can i append the json object into the javascript file?

Tags: node.js

I have one file called `benches.js`

```
const data = {
    bench_01: {
        name: 'bench_01',
        prototype: 'items',
        objectID: 'bench_01',
    }
}

export default data;
```

I have an object like:

```
{
  bench_02: {
    name: "bench_02",
    prototype: "items",
    objectID: "bench_02",
  }
}
```

I need to append this object into above `benches.js` file using nodeJS.

How can i append this object into file before export default?

I need the output like :

```
const data = {
        bench_01: {
            name: 'bench_01',
            prototype: 'items',
            objectID: 'bench_01',
        },
        bench_02: {
            name: "bench_02",
            prototype: "items",
            objectID: "bench_02",
        }
    }

export default data;
```